# Get specific record of each image

Tags: php, html

In this foreach I get all the records that the user made, I get to know what he did by the description, but I would also like to add the document image made by each user.

I have 4 columns in the specific database for each image, but how can I get them in addition to the description only?

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($allAtividades as $atividade)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$atividade['id']}}</td>
        <td>{{$atividade->getUser()->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$atividade['ip']}}</td>
        <td>{{$atividade['description']}}</td>
        <td>{{$atividade['created_at']}}</td>
        <td>
            <span class="badge">
                <img src="{{$atividade->getUser()->doc1}}"width="30" heigth="30" data-container="body" tabindex="0"  alt="User Avatar" data-html='true' style="cursor:pointer;">
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Comment: What is the reason for having 4 tables for 1 image?

Comment: no, sorry for the translation, I said 4 tables for each 1 image

Comment: You need to show us your database schema, example data, how the tables are connected/references and what the expected result should be. You should also include your current code for fetching the data.

Comment: I have 4 tables 1 for each image, doc1, doc2, doc3 and doc4. Foreach gets the correct description, I believed that only with the html I got the result of the image

Comment: That still makes rather little sense. Do you really mean _tables_, or are you maybe actually trying to say _columns_ …?

Comment: yes, excuse they are columns, they are structures inside the `users` table, I will change the text.